# autocomplete through ajax

Tags: ajax, http, autocomplete

I want to suggest results using auto-complete. I need to send AJAX requests on each keystroke. For this I want to keep the HTTP connection open for few seconds and if something is typed within that period, I want to send the AJAX in that same connection. If nothing is typed in that period, I want to close the HTTP connection.

Background:

I already use typewatch plugin. But here the HTTP connections are made each time I send a request. I still want to improve the speed. I read in this thread http://www.philwhln.com/quoras-technology-examined#the-search-box that:

> Quora uses persistent connections. A
>   HTTP connection is established with
>   the server when you start typing the
>   search query.

How can I do this with cross browser support? Is it just keep-alive?

Comment: A lot of what they're discussing in this article is how they sped up their server-side results.  They go on to say that typing 9 characters results in 9 requests, the persistent connection makes no difference in speed, just in the number of connections.  Perhaps you should try reducing your typewatch delay to 30-50 ms, or remove it altogether since the purpose of typewatch is to reduce the number of requests, not make autocomplete faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Each request-response round trip is asynchronous, meaning that when it's sent, it waits for that particular request's response to return, then handles it.

What I think you want to do is prevent your script from hammering the server.  To do this there are a variety of methods, but the most common is to use a keystroke timer.  The timer waits a specified number of milliseconds after the user finishes typing before sending the request, containing the textbox's value, to the server.

If you're using JQuery you can use the [TypeWatch](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TypeWatch) plugin to do this.  JQuery will also satisfy your cross browser requirements.

**However**, since you also want to do auto-complete, you may as well use the JQuery [AutoComplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) plugin which also has a keystroke timer built in, by default it's set to 400 millseconds.  Click the **OPTIONS TAB** on [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) to see what all the configuration options are that you can pass into the plugin.